# Vaadin: open new window with ABSOLUTE url path from a BUTTON

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a table with addresses. I have a button you can click which I want to open a google search for the address in a separate window. I have tried this code with [`BrowserWindowOpener`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html).

```
getUI().getPage().open(url, "_blank")
```

and

```
BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(url);
opener.extend(googleBtn)
```

but both are appending my url to the current path. I want to simply run a search in google in a separate window. I'm sure this is much simpler than I'm making it. It sure should be, at least. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, see example of `BrowserWindowOpener` in The Book of Vaadin [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-printing.html) and [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-windows.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brimby, you were right with your second try. The [`BrowserWindowOpener`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html) extension is the way to go. You should use an [`ExternalResource`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/server/ExternalResource.html) instance with an absolute URL like this:

```
public class OpenGoogleUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        BrowserWindowOpener extension = new BrowserWindowOpener(new ExternalResource("https://www.google.by/#q=vaadin"));
        Button button = new Button("Open Google");
        extension.extend(button);
        setContent(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed work with Vaadin 7.6.4 in Safari browser.

Comment: This code snippet should be part of the Book of Vaadin

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Hyperlink to a given URL
Link link = new Link("Google It",
        new ExternalResource("https://www.google.by/#q=search+query"));

// Open the URL in a new window/tab
link.setTargetName("_blank");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it super clear, but I need it from a button, not just a link. You know of anything?

Comment: The part I wanted, link.setTargetName("_blank");, worked for me. Thanks!